# PrimeNG p-menubar align one item to right

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I'm working with **PrimeNG 8.1.1** and I would like to push one of the items to the right side (the submenu of logout, and profile).

**Any suggeestions please?**

```js
    this._menuItems = [
          {
            label: 'Dashboard',
            routerLink: '/dashboard'
          },
          {
            icon:'pi pi-fw pi-user',
            items: [
              {
                label: 'Profile',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user',
                command:()=> this.profile(),
              },
              {
                label: 'Logout',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-sign-out',
                command:()=> this.logout(),
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Full disclosure: I'm new to this, so this may not be the best solution.
Tested on primeng 11.4.2

The menu bar is a flex container, so we *should* be able to push items around by using standard flex ideas - see [Aligning flex items on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container). As with other answers here, we make use of the `style` property of the menu item to control how it's displayed, in this case we need to use `margin-left: auto` to push the item to the right.

The problem I encountered was that the `p-menubarsub` component does not occupy 100% of the available width, so using `margin-left` by itself has no effect as there is no space available to move items around.

Once this is fixed, it seemed to work for me.

component.css

```
:host ::ng-deep p-menubarsub {
    width: 100%;
}
```

component.html

```
<p-menubar [model]="mainMenu">
    <ng-template pTemplate="start">
        <h4>Welcome</h4>
    </ng-template>
</p-menubar>
```

component.ts

```
export class .... {
  mainMenu: MenuItem[] = [
    {label: 'Left menu item'},
    {label: 'Right menu item', style: {'margin-left': 'auto'}
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

If we check the compiled code from prime, we can see that "icon" actually just means class. This means that we can add a custom class to icon without affecting our icon.

```
this._menuItems = [
      {
        label: 'Dashboard',
        routerLink: '/dashboard'
      },
      {
        icon:'pi pi-fw pi-user',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'Profile',
            icon: 'my-margin-left pi pi-fw pi-user',
            command:()=> this.profile(),
          },
          {
            label: 'Logout',
            icon: 'my-margin-left pi pi-fw pi-sign-out',
            command:()=> this.logout(),
          }
        ]
      }
  ]
```

Now in our Styles.css we can simply add

```
.layout-wrapper .layout-menu li a > .my-margin-left {
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

This will add the css for all items in the menu with that class. This solution will work for both menu and submenu items.

Comment: I tried your exact example and it doesn't work.  I'm not sure what I'm missing. :(

Comment: Hi Travis, are you using the same version of Prime? The sollution I posted above might no longer be valid for prime 9 or 10.

Answer (score 0):

For version PrimeNG 11.2.0 you have two options.

(1) Using styleClass property:

```
this._menuItems = [
      {
        label: 'Dashboard',
        routerLink: '/dashboard'
      },
      {
        icon:'pi pi-fw pi-user',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'Profile',
            icon: 'my-margin-left pi pi-fw pi-user',
            command:()=> this.profile(),
          },
          {
            label: 'Logout',
            styleClass: 'p-ml-6',
            icon: 'my-margin-left pi pi-fw pi-sign-out',
            command:()=> this.logout(),
          }
        ]
      }
  ]
```

(2) or Using *ng-template pTemplate="end"* on HTML:

```
<p-menubar [model]="items">
    <ng-template pTemplate="end">
        <button type="button" pButton label="Logout" icon="pi pi-sign-out"></button>
    </ng-template>
</p-menubar>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also been searching for a solution to this issue since NgPrime is not as dynamic as I initially thought. However, you can resolve it in the following way:

component.css:

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-menubar {
  position: relative;
  height: 8vh;
}

:host ::ng-deep .p-menubar .p-menubar-button{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-135%);
}

/* modifcar tamaño Mayor a 960px */
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  :host ::ng-deep  .p-menubar-root-list>li:last-child .p-submenu-list {
    right: 0;
  }

  :host ::ng-deep .p-menubar .p-menubar-root-list {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-5%) translateY(-115%);
  }
}
```

component.html

```
<p-menubar [model]="items"></p-menubar>
```

with this result:
[image]